# How to compute distance between two vectors based on measures?

Tags: matlab, matrix, euclidean-distance

I want to compute the average of distances between each column  and other columns in a matrix except itself.

I wrote this code:

```
For i=1:m
  For j=1:m-1
    If(i==j)
      d=0;
    Else
      d=pdist2(a(:,i),a(:,j),'jaccard');
      s=sum(d)/(m-1);
    End
  End
End
```

The matrix is nxm.

I know that pdist2 function support some distance measures like jaccard , cosine , hamming , euclidean....

But If I want to compute canberra or clark distance measures or measures like them, I should define a function in pdist2 this way:

```
D=pdist2(x,y,@distfun)
```

I wanted to know how to define a distance function for these measures?

---

Edit: The aim is to then empirically obtain the point where the values start to decrease but the figures don't show this...

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Canberra Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canberra_distance) is defined as

[image: equation]

You are passing two column vectors into `pdist2`, so we can implement the above equation as an anonymous function which accepts to vector inputs...

```
fCanberraDist = @(p,q) sum( abs(p - q) ./ ( abs(p) + abs(q) ) );
```

Now you have the function handle, you can use the following:

```
% ... previous code
d = pdist2( a(:,i), a(:,j), fCanberraDist );
% ... further code
```

Note you're not currently doing anything with your result, I'm assuming that's just for the sake of the example code.

You can define any other custom distance measure in a similar way, as either an anonymous function or a fully separate function (in its own .m file or defined locally).

Comment: After the loop, I want to use plot(s) to plot the m disrances and maybe I can find a threshold for these values.Is It practical to find a threshold from the figure of the values?or there is a better procedure?

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "find a threshold" - what would be the criteria for this threshold? If you can define it mathematically then it's better to do programmatically.

Comment: I want to empirically obtain the point where the values start to decrease but the figures don't show this, for example,  I attached the figure of Canberra distances in my question. You mean that I should define It mathematically first.

Comment: I have answered your original question, I can't tell you why a figure you've produced doesn't show the results you expected... You've not given a [mcve] to reproduce these results, or any explanation as to why they aren't as expected? This perhaps needs its own question, if the original question here about implementing a custom distance measure has been answered. Please mark my answer as accepted if this is the case.